# Get most recent files recursively with PHP

Tags: php, file

I am looking for code which lists the five most recent files in a directory recursively.

This is non-recursive code, and would be perfect for me if it was recursive:

```
<?php

$show = 0; // Leave as 0 for all
$dir = 'sat/'; // Leave as blank for current

if($dir) chdir($dir);
$files = glob( '*.{html,php,php4,txt}', GLOB_BRACE );
usort( $files, 'filemtime_compare' );

function filemtime_compare( $a, $b )
{
    return filemtime( $b ) - filemtime( $a );
}
$i = 0;
foreach ( $files as $file )
{
    ++$i;
    if ( $i == $show ) break;
    echo $file . ' - ' . date( 'D, d M y H:i:s', filemtime($file) ) . '<br />' . "\n";  /* This is the output line */
}
?>
```

It is possible to modify it to scan directories recursively?

Comment: What do you mean recursively?  You want to list the five most recently touched files in a given directory and all of its subdirectories?

Comment: Yes, yes! "list the five most recently touched files in a given directory and all of its subdirectories"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25257717/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/49297569/2943403

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53176120/2943403

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php#111217

Answer (score 2):

This was my first version (tested, working):

```
function latest($searchDir, array $files = array()) {
    $search = opendir($searchDir);

    $dirs = array();
    while($item = readdir($search)) {
        if ($item == '.' || $item == '..') { continue; }
        if (is_dir($searchDir.'/'.$item)) {
            $dirs[] = $searchDir.'/'.$item;
        }
        if (is_file($searchDir.'/'.$item)) {
            $ftime = filemtime($searchDir.'/'.$item);
            $files[$ftime] = $searchDir.'/'.$item;
        }
    }
    closedir($search);
    if (count($dirs) > 0) {
        foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
            $files += latest($dir,$files);
        }
    }
    krsort($files);
    $files = array_slice($files, 0, 5, true);
    return $files;
}
```

But I like byte's usage of `glob()`, so here is a slightly modified version of his to return the same format:

```
function top5modsEx($dir) {
    $mods = array();
    foreach (glob($dir . '/*') as $f) {
        $mods[filemtime($f)] = $f;
    }
    krsort($mods);
    return array_slice($mods, 0, 5, true);
}
```

This returns the time (UNIX Timestamp format) that the file was modified as the key of the element in the array.

Comment: Working like a charm! Is there any way to exclude files from the search?

Comment: || $item == 'exclude this' --- this is the solution.

Thank you very much again!

Comment: Trying to run this on a windows to help with upgrades to a script and the first script works like it should.  However, the second one doesn't list anything recursively and just does the initial directory.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty quick and dirty, and untested, but might get you started:

```
function top5mods($dir)
{
  $mods = array();
  foreach (glob($dir . '/*') as $f) {
    $mods[] = filemtime($f);
  }
  sort($mods);
  $mods = array_reverse($mods);
  return array_slice($mods, 0, 5);
}
```

Comment: `glob` is not recursive.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [solution](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php#96326) in the PHP manual.

Comment: Link-only answers to documentation are hints that can be posted as comments under the question.  This answer is vague and low-value.

Answer (score 0):

Edit : Sorry I didn't see the part "recursively".

To get RECENTS files first (html for example), please sort like this with anonymous function :

```
$myarray = glob("*.*.html");
usort($myarray, function($a,$b){
  return filemtime($b) - filemtime($a);
});
```

And to get it recursively you can :

```
function glob_recursive($pattern, $flags = 0) {
    $files = glob($pattern, $flags);
    foreach (glob(dirname($pattern).'/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR|GLOB_NOSORT) as $dir) {
        $files = array_merge($files, glob_recursive($dir.'/'.basename($pattern), $flags));
    }
    return $files;
}
```

So, replace then the glob function by :

```
$myarray = glob_recursive("*.*.html");
usort($myarray, function($a,$b){
  return filemtime($b) - filemtime($a);
});
```

Comment: Please read the question requirements before posting an answer so that you know exactly what a proposed solution MUST do.  Did you test your suggestion before posting it?

Comment: You are expected to announce where you source code from when you are not the author.  This is plagarism otherwise.

Comment: this in one my projets... but feel free to delete it if you want :)

Comment: I have linked several posts (as comments under the question) in Stackoverflow which are using the exact same custom function. I am also not sure that you have the sorting correct.  Did you test your answer?

Comment: I've tested it this afternoon MickMackUSA. If you inverse $a & $b, you have oldest first. Thank you for your time and please, tell me how different can I offer an sorting function for get files by timestamp ?

Comment: Proof that you are sorting ASC instead of DESC as desired by the OP: https://3v4l.org/DGsc5  The most recent files will have the highest unix stamp. The OP doesn't need help with this though -- the correct sorting is already in the question.  This question is asking about the recursive search for files.

Comment: Weird, I past the wrong line indeed ! I just doublerse check on my website where I display latest uploaded images :) thanks for your time.