# PHP get file listing including sub directories

Tags: php, glob

I am trying to retrieve all images in a directory, including all subdirectories. I am currently using

```
$images = glob("{images/portfolio/*.jpg,images/portfolio/*/*.jpg,images/portfolio/*/*/*.jpg,images/portfolio/*/*/*/*.jpg}",GLOB_BRACE);
```

This works, however the results are:

```
images/portfolio/1.jpg
images/portfolio/2.jpg
images/portfolio/subdirectory1/1.jpg
images/portfolio/subdirectory1/2.jpg
images/portfolio/subdirectory2/1.jpg
images/portfolio/subdirectory2/2.jpg
images/portfolio/subdirectory1/subdirectory1/1.jpg
images/portfolio/subdirectory1/subdirectory1/2.jpg
```

I want it to do a whole directory branch at a time so the results are:

```
images/portfolio/1.jpg
images/portfolio/2.jpg
images/portfolio/subdirectory1/1.jpg
images/portfolio/subdirectory1/2.jpg
images/portfolio/subdirectory1/subdirectory1/1.jpg
images/portfolio/subdirectory1/subdirectory1/2.jpg
images/portfolio/subdirectory2/1.jpg
images/portfolio/subdirectory2/2.jpg
```

Greatly appreciate any help, cheers!

P.S It would also be great if I could just get all subdirectories under portfolio without having to specifically state each directory with a wild card.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

from [glob example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php#106595)

```
if ( ! function_exists('glob_recursive'))
{
    // Does not support flag GLOB_BRACE        
   function glob_recursive($pattern, $flags = 0)
   {
     $files = glob($pattern, $flags);
     foreach (glob(dirname($pattern).'/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR|GLOB_NOSORT) as $dir)
     {
       $files = array_merge($files, glob_recursive($dir.'/'.basename($pattern), $flags));
     }
     return $files;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks diEcho, had just looked at that page before posting and completely missed that example. Cheers!

Answer (score 24):

**Solution**:

```
<?php
$path = realpath('yourfolder/examplefolder');
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path)) as $filename)
{
        echo "$filename</br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: How does this deal with file name patterns?

Comment: First grab them all in one array and then filter them using foreach and if statements :)

Comment: the `glob_recursive` method returns an array in alphabetical order, while using these recursive iterators returns the files in a seemingly random order. Keep it in mind if order is an issue.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a simpler approach:

Instead of using:

```
$path = realpath('yourfolder/examplefolder/*');
glob($path);
```

You'll have to use:

```
$path = realpath('yourfolder/examplefolder').'/{**/*,*}';
glob($path, GLOB_BRACE);
```

This last one will use bracing, and it is, in fact, a shorthand for this code:

```
$path = realpath('yourfolder/examplefolder');

$self_files = glob($path . '/*');
$recursive_files = glob($path . '/**/*');

$all_files = $self_files + $recursive_files; // That's the result you want
```

---

You may also want to filter directories from your result. `glob()` function has `GLOB_ONLYDIR` flag. Let's use it to diff out our result.

```
$path =  realpath('yourfolder/examplefolder/') . '{**/*,*}';

$all_files = array_diff(
  glob($path, GLOB_BRACE),
  glob($path, GLOB_BRACE | GLOB_ONLYDIR)
);
```

Comment: realpath() does not accept more than 1 parameter, and I do not believe it supports glob patters either.

Comment: Warning: realpath() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given

`$path = realpath('yourfolder/examplefolder/{**/*,*}', GLOB_BRACE);`

And `glob($path . '/**/*');` is unable to list files and folders recursively.

Comment: I think you have mistyped something. In my example we pass only one argument into `realpath`.

Comment: In your second example block you are passing GLOB_BRACE as realpath parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This function supports GLOB_BRACE:

```
function rglob($pattern_in, $flags = 0) {
    $patterns = array ();
    if ($flags & GLOB_BRACE) {
        $matches;
        if (preg_match_all ( '#\{[^.\}]*\}#i', $pattern_in, $matches )) {
            // Get all GLOB_BRACE entries.
            $brace_entries = array ();
            foreach ( $matches [0] as $index => $match ) {
                $brace_entries [$index] = explode ( ',', substr ( $match, 1, - 1 ) );
            }

            // Create cartesian product.
            // @source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311779/finding-cartesian-product-with-php-associative-arrays
            $cart = array (
                    array () 
            );
            foreach ( $brace_entries as $key => $values ) {
                $append = array ();
                foreach ( $cart as $product ) {
                    foreach ( $values as $item ) {
                        $product [$key] = $item;
                        $append [] = $product;
                    }
                }
                $cart = $append;
            }

            // Create multiple glob patterns based on the cartesian product.
            foreach ( $cart as $vals ) {
                $c_pattern = $pattern_in;
                foreach ( $vals as $index => $val ) {
                    $c_pattern = preg_replace ( '/' . $matches [0] [$index] . '/', $val, $c_pattern, 1 );
                }
                $patterns [] = $c_pattern;
            }
        } else
            $patterns [] = $pattern_in;
    } else
        $patterns [] = $pattern_in;

    // @source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php#106595
    $result = array ();
    foreach ( $patterns as $pattern ) {
        $files = glob ( $pattern, $flags );
        foreach ( glob ( dirname ( $pattern ) . '/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR | GLOB_NOSORT ) as $dir ) {
            $files = array_merge ( $files, rglob ( $dir . '/' . basename ( $pattern ), $flags ) );
        }
        $result = array_merge ( $result, $files );
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple class:

```
<?php
    class AllFiles {
        public $files = [];
        function __construct($folder) {
            $this->read($folder);           
        }
        function read($folder) {
            $folders = glob("$folder/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
            foreach ($folders as $folder) {
                $this->files[] = $folder . "/";
                $this->read( $folder );
            }
            $files = array_filter(glob("$folder/*"), 'is_file');
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                $this->files[] = $file;             
            }
        }
        function __toString() {
            return implode( "\n", $this->files );
        }
    };

    $allfiles = new AllFiles("baseq3");
    echo $allfiles;
```

Example output:

```
baseq3/gfx/
baseq3/gfx/2d/
baseq3/gfx/2d/numbers/
baseq3/gfx/2d/numbers/eight_32b.tga
baseq3/gfx/2d/numbers/five_32b.tga
baseq3/gfx/2d/numbers/four_32b.tga
baseq3/gfx/2d/numbers/minus_32b.tga
baseq3/gfx/2d/numbers/nine_32b.tga
```

If you don't want the folders in the list, just comment this line out:

```
$this->files[] = $folder . "/";
```