# Count how many files in directory PHP

Tags: php, file, count, directory

I'm working on a slightly new project. I wanted to know how many files are in a certain directory.

```
<div id="header">
<?php 
    $dir = opendir('uploads/'); # This is the directory it will count from
    $i = 0; # Integer starts at 0 before counting

    # While false is not equal to the filedirectory
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) { 
        if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..') and !is_dir($file)) $i++;
    }

    echo "There were $i files"; # Prints out how many were in the directory
?>
</div>
```

This is what I have so far (from searching). However, it is not appearing properly? I have added a few notes so feel free to remove them, they are just so I can understand it as best as I can.

If you require some more information or feel as if I haven't described this enough please feel free to state so.

Comment: It would be shorter to use an idiom like `count(scandir("uploads/")) - 2` than that loop.

Comment: @mario **Careful!** *scandir* is nice, but -2 is not exactly the best - you can be in a root directory or the directory can have directories inside - **Laurent Brieu has a nice check for ./.. and directories** :)

Answer (score 311, accepted):

You can simply do the following :

```
$fi = new FilesystemIterator(__DIR__, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
printf("There were %d Files", iterator_count($fi));
```

Comment: You don't need to pass in the flag `FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS` as that's default anyway.

Comment: Is it possible to look for specific filetypes with FilesystemIterator?  It looks not possible with the docs, but I may be misreading something important.  Otherwise something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42264823/how-to-count-number-of-txt-files-in-a-directory-in-php) would do

Answer (score 97):

You can get the filecount like so:

```
$directory = "/path/to/dir/";
$filecount = count(glob($directory . "*"));
echo "There were $filecount files";
```

where the `"*"` is you can change that to a specific filetype if you want like `"*.jpg"` or you could do multiple filetypes like this:

```
glob($directory . "*.{jpg,png,gif}",GLOB_BRACE)
```

the `GLOB_BRACE` flag expands {a,b,c} to match 'a', 'b', or 'c'

> **Note** that `glob()` skips Linux hidden files, or all files whose names are starting from a dot, i.e. `.htaccess`.

Comment: Awesome, there are a lot of possibilities with this approach to filter files as well as count them :) Creating a simple loop and several conditions would be great... But how can you include other directories within that directories and so on to count all files and exclude directories from the count?

Comment: @TheBumpaster  
check out this SO question/answers on how to scan subdirectories with glob: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12109042/276250

Comment: For whom this solution doesn't work, add `__DIR__ . ` before `"/path/to/dir/"` (`__DIR__ . "/path/to/dir/"`)

Comment: @dnns Actually adding anything to `/path/to/dir` would fail it, because first `/` means `starting from root dir`. If there were `path/to/dir`, then yes, `__DIR__ . '/path/to/dir'` would help (in this case you must use `/` after `__DIR__`

Answer (score 57):

Try this.

```
// Directory
$directory = "/dir";

// Returns an array of files
$files = scandir($directory);

// Count the number of files and store them inside the variable..
// Removing 2 because we do not count '.' and '..'.
$num_files = count($files)-2;
```

Comment: Maybe `$num_files = count($files) - 2;` ? Because of `.` as well as `..`

Comment: Note, that it will also count these two : '.' and '..'

Comment: to get rid of the `.` and `..` try this: $files = `array_diff( scandir("/dir"), array(".", "..") );`

Comment: `array_slice(scandir($directory),2)`

Comment: fix (  Should be $num_files = (count($files)-2);

Answer (score 44):

You should have :

```
<div id="header">
<?php 
    // integer starts at 0 before counting
    $i = 0; 
    $dir = 'uploads/';
    if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false){
            if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..')) && !is_dir($dir.$file)) 
                $i++;
        }
    }
    // prints out how many were in the directory
    echo "There were $i files";
?>
</div>
```

Comment: it is the same code and doesn't work: $file = readdir($dh) should be $file = readdir($dir)

Comment: It would be nice (and helpfull before all) to point out the differences / mistakes the OP has made in a minimalistic text.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for this. It still won't appear for me however I feel that might be to do with my stylesheet or something along those lines.

Either way thanks very much for your help.

Edit: Fixed :) Thanks very much!

Comment: Dont forget to close the directory :)

Answer (score 41):

The best answer in my opinion:

```
$num = count(glob("/exact/path/to/files/" . "*"));
echo $num;
```

- It doesnt counts . and ..
- Its a one liner
- Im proud of it

Comment: Just realised you can use "folder/*" if your PHP document is in the same directory!

Comment: One liners should have reputation rewards x2 ...  actually make it x3

Comment: What do you mean? "It doesn't count".

Comment: They mean that it doesn't count dots/periods (`.` or `..`) that represent the current and parent directories.

Answer (score 16):

Since I needed this too, I was curious as to which alternative was the fastest.

I found that -- if all you want is a file count -- Baba's solution is **a lot** faster than the others. I was quite surprised.

Try it out for yourself:

```
<?php
define('MYDIR', '...');

foreach (array(1, 2, 3) as $i)
{
    $t = microtime(true);
    $count = run($i);
    echo "$i: $count (".(microtime(true) - $t)." s)\n";
}

function run ($n)
{
    $func = "countFiles$n";
    $x = 0;
    for ($f = 0; $f < 5000; $f++)
        $x = $func();
    return $x;
}

function countFiles1 ()
{
    $dir = opendir(MYDIR);
    $c = 0;
    while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false)
        if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..')))
            $c++;
    closedir($dir);
    return $c;
}

function countFiles2 ()
{
    chdir(MYDIR);
    return count(glob("*"));
}

function countFiles3 () // Fastest method
{
    $f = new FilesystemIterator(MYDIR, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
    return iterator_count($f);
}
?>
```

Test run: (obviously, `glob()` doesn't count dot-files)

```
1: 99 (0.4815571308136 s)
2: 98 (0.96104407310486 s)
3: 99 (0.26513481140137 s)
```

Comment: Finally which one is faster as you didn't mentioned result?

Comment: I did say that Baba's solution was fastest, but of course I should've been clearer about the results. Fixed now.

Answer (score 12):

Working Demo

```
<?php

$directory = "../images/team/harry/"; // dir location
if (glob($directory . "*.*") != false)
{
 $filecount = count(glob($directory . "*.*"));
 echo $filecount;
}
else
{
 echo 0;
}

?>
```

Comment: I would avoid calling glob() 2 times if you have lots of files in directory. Instead I would assign result of first glob into variable and use count on this variable.

Answer (score 7):

I use this:

```
count(glob("yourdir/*",GLOB_BRACE))
```

Comment: This is the first that works for me, but has the problem that it does not gives you assurance that all files counted are images.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php echo(count(array_slice(scandir($directory),2))); ?>
```

`array_slice` works similary like `substr` function, only it works with arrays.

For example, this would chop out first two array keys from array:

```
$key_zero_one = array_slice($someArray, 0, 2);
```

And if You ommit the first parameter, like in first example, array will not contain first two key/value pairs *('.' and '..').

Comment: This is basically the same answer as has already been proposed by other posters. Can you improve on your answer, or add any more information other than has already been discussed?

Comment: Better .. ? Let them read php.net manual a little bit more than usual. :)

Answer (score 3):

Based on the accepted answer, here is a way to count all files in a directory RECURSIVELY:

```
iterator_count(
    new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator('/your/directory/here/', \FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS)
    )
)
```

Comment: true answer here! tnx

Answer (score 1):

```
$it = new filesystemiterator(dirname("Enter directory here"));
printf("There were %d Files", iterator_count($it));
echo("<br/>");
    foreach ($it as $fileinfo) {
        echo $fileinfo->getFilename() . "<br/>\n";
    }
```

This should work
enter the directory in dirname. and let the magic happen.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe usefull to someone. On a Windows system, you can let Windows do the job by calling the dir-command. I use an absolute path, like `E:/mydir/mysubdir`.

```
<?php 
$mydir='E:/mydir/mysubdir';
$dir=str_replace('/','\\',$mydir);
$total = exec('dir '.$dir.' /b/a-d | find /v /c "::"');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$files = glob('uploads/*');
$count = 0;
$totalCount = 0;
$subFileCount = 0;
foreach ($files as $file) 
{  
    global $count, $totalCount;
    if(is_dir($file))
    {
        $totalCount += getFileCount($file);
    }
    if(is_file($file))
    {
        $count++;  
    }  
}

function getFileCount($dir)
{
    global $subFileCount;
    if(is_dir($dir))
    {
        $subfiles = glob($dir.'/*');
        if(count($subfiles))
        {      
            foreach ($subfiles as $file) 
            {
                getFileCount($file);
            }
        }
    }
    if(is_file($dir))
    {
        $subFileCount++;
    }
    return $subFileCount;
}

$totalFilesCount = $count + $totalCount; 
echo 'Total Files Count ' . $totalFilesCount;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a PHP Linux function that's considerably fast. A bit dirty, but it gets the job done!

$dir - path to directory

$type - f, d or false (by default)

f - returns only files count

d - returns only folders count

false - returns total files and folders count

```
function folderfiles($dir, $type=false) {
    $f = escapeshellarg($dir);
    if($type == 'f') {
        $io = popen ( '/usr/bin/find ' . $f . ' -type f | wc -l', 'r' );
    } elseif($type == 'd') {
        $io = popen ( '/usr/bin/find ' . $f . ' -type d | wc -l', 'r' );
    } else {
        $io = popen ( '/usr/bin/find ' . $f . ' | wc -l', 'r' );
    }

    $size = fgets ( $io, 4096);
    pclose ( $io );
    return $size;
}
```

You can tweak to fit your needs.

Please note that this will not work on Windows.

Answer (score -2):

```
  simple code add for file .php then your folder which number of file to count its      

    $directory = "images/icons";
    $files = scandir($directory);
    for($i = 0 ; $i < count($files) ; $i++){
        if($files[$i] !='.' && $files[$i] !='..')
        { echo $files[$i]; echo "<br>";
            $file_new[] = $files[$i];
        }
    }
    echo $num_files = count($file_new);
```

simple add its done ....

Comment: add some explanation to your code to make it clearer.