# Count number of files in folder in php

Tags: php

```
<?php 
$directory = '/var/www/ajaxform/';
if (glob($directory . '.jpg') != false)
{
    $filecount = count(glob($directory . '*.jpg'));
    echo $filecount;
}
else
{
    echo 0;
}
?>
```

there are four jpg images in this directory but it returns `0`

Comment: You are missing a * in your `if`

Comment: Array ( [0] => /var/www/ajaxform/image.jpg )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count how many files in directory php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801370/count-how-many-files-in-directory-php)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[Glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) returns an `array`, on error it returns `false`.

Try this:

```
$directory = '/var/www/ajaxform/';
$files = glob($directory . '*.jpg');

if ( $files !== false )
{
    $filecount = count( $files );
    echo $filecount;
}
else
{
    echo 0;
}
```

Comment: You have an extra parentheses. Should read as `$filecount = count( $files );`

Comment: I used this on my server, I had to remove the first `/` in `$directory`.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
<?php 
$directory = '/var/www/ajaxform/';
if (glob($directory . '*.jpg') != false)
{
 $filecount = count(glob($directory . '*.jpg'));
 echo $filecount;
}
else
{
 echo 0;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a mistake in your glob pattern (in the if). You are missing a *:

```
glob($directory . '*.jpg')
```

should work

Answer (score 3):

Minimalization approach:

```
function getImagesNo($path)
{
  return ($files=glob($path.'*.jpg')) ? count($files) : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

glob is case sensitive, according to the PHP docs.  Are your extensions lowercase?  Does the executing account have access to /var/www/ajaxform/?

Answer (score 0):

Just try this--

```
if (glob($directory . "*.jpg") != false)
$filecount = count(glob($directory . "*.jpg"));
else
$filecount = 0;
```