# PHP renaming files after a limit

Tags: php, limit, file-rename

I want to make a php script that when the images folder has 30 images the next one uploaded becomes 1.JPEG and the rest go up one but the image which was 30.JPEG gets deleted because there is a 30 image limit. Would this even be possible to do?
This is what I have tried so far but it gives a unexpected ";" error

```
<?php
 if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
   $errors= array();
   $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
   $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
   $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
   $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
   $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));

   $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

   if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
     $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
   }

   if($file_size > 2097152) {
      $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
   }
  for ($file_tmp = 29; $i > 0; $i--)
 for ($i = 29; $i > 0; $i--)
 {
 if (file_exists($file_tmp.".jpg");
     rename($file_tmp.".jpg",($file_tmp+1).".jpg");
 }      
  if(empty($errors)==true) {
     move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name);
     echo "Success";
  }else{
     print_r($errors);
      }
   }
?>
```

Comment: please show us what you have tried so far and where you are struggling with this problem.

Comment: Hi Florian I just have a simple php upload script but I was wondering if this is theoretically possible

Comment: These may help you some http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801370/count-how-many-files-in-directory-php - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194173/count-number-of-files-in-folder-in-php

Comment: It's theoretically possible.

Comment: if I understood your question correctly, I would say it is possible. There is the `rename` function to rename a file, and you can check with a for loop through all filenames

Comment: Thank you I will give it a go :)

Answer (score 3):

I would do it like this:

```
for ($i = 29; $i > 0; $i--)
{
    if (file_exists($i.".jpg");
         rename($i.".jpg",($i+1).".jpg");
}
```

Now save your new file as "1.jpg".

I'm sure you could have come up with a similar solution rather quick.