# php counting number of files in a directory

Tags: php, counting

i am trying to display a number from which is the amount of files in a folder in my directory within my website.

i have tried to do many methods of this which i have found on the net but still have no clue maybe its because i am unsure of the location of the directory

the location of the folder is

```
www/documents
```

and here is my code

```
<?php iterator_count(new DirectoryIterator('/documents/'));?>
```

i have tried a few samples i found on the net.

---

server details

---

```
its a usb device with UniServer
```

This is why i am not sure where the file structure starts

I am very novice so please play fair and not scare me with them words that means monkey beans to me :)

thanks in advance

---

Locations i have tried

---

```
www/documents
/www/documents/
```

Comment: Have you tried using full path instead ?

Comment: i will update my question with the locations i have tried

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801370/count-how-many-files-in-directory-php

Comment: Try `new DirectoryIterator(__DIR__ . '/documents/')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shorter version:

```
<?php

echo count(glob("/var/documents/*"));

?>
```