# Images in folder as a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php

I want to have a javascript variable that is equal to the amount of pictures in the directory where the javascript file is.

There are 2 things I don't know how to do:

1) Get the number of images in the folder using PHP.

2) Transfer this data to javascript.

There are many versions of each of the steps online, but I don't understand how to combine them and I don't know which way to choose.

Please help me understand what I need to do in order to get these 2 done.

Answer (score 2):

1. For couting number of images into folder,

```
$imgs = scandir($dir);
$f = count($imgs);
echo $f;
```

2 . get value into js variable.

Now for that make ajax call to php and write step first code and into success callback of ajax set js variable value to the response you received from php code.

For couting images you can also use different code.

[Count how many files in directory php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801370/count-how-many-files-in-directory-php)

**Example**

create new php file and name it whatever you want, but for this example i am giving it `ajax.php` and i will demonstrate you `jQuery` example code.

now in `ajax.php` file write below code.

```
$imgs = scandir($dir);
$f = count($imgs);
echo $f;
```

now in index.php file add below code,

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
        var jsvar;

        $.ajax(
        {
            url : 'ajax.php',
            type : 'get',
            success : function(response)
            {
                jsvar = response;
            }
        });
        alert(jsvar);
    });
</script>
```

after pasting above code and save it and run in browser, you will see alert showing count of total number of images it have.

`jsvar` is the javascript variable that you want to store total images count.

Comment: Can you please go more into details about that ajax call? I don't even know what ajax is.

Comment: @OriShuss are you comfortable with jQuery.?

Comment: No, I'm planning to learn but not yet..
If it's a basic code though I guess that if you explain what each row does I can understand.

Comment: By index.php do you mean index.html? Or is it another php file

Comment: @OriShuss yes its same....but main thing is paste js code into page on which you want to set jsvalue

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40030/discussion-between-orishuss-and-dipesh-parmar)