# PHP file tree - Listing Total Files

Tags: php

### PHP Script

```
<?php
    echo '<ul class="DirView"><li><a href="#">Recently Used<span>28</span></a></li>';
    $path = "../Desktop/IMG/BananzaNews/";
    $dir = new DirectoryIterator($path);
    foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
        if ($fileinfo->isDir() && !$fileinfo->isDot()) {
            $subPath = $path.$fileinfo->getFilename();
            $subDir = new DirectoryIterator($subPath);
            $count = count(glob($subPath. "/*.*"));
            echo '<li><a href="#">'.$fileinfo->getFilename().'<span>'.$count.'</span></a><ul class="sub-menu">';
            foreach ($subDir as $subPath) {
                if ($subPath->isDir() && !$subPath->isDot()) {
                    $file = $subPath->getFilename();
                    $fullPath = $path.$subPath.'/'.$file.'/*.*';
                    $inFullPath = count(glob($fullPath. '/*.*'));
                    echo '<li><a href="#">'.$file.'<span>44</span></a><li>';
                }
            }
            echo '</ul></li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
?>
```

### Result

[image: My PHP File Tree Preview]

### The Problem

Only ignoring the 'recently used' category, the rest fully reads my directories of which are duplicated for testing purposes. As you can see, each sub_category has 44 files inside.

What I now want to do is count the total files (44 + 44) and display them on their parent category (88) however as I've already written this to my page, is this possible or is a bit of re-scripting needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. replace all your code.

```
 <?php
echo '<ul class="DirView"><li><a href="#">Recently Used<span>28</span></a></li>';
$path = "./images/";
$dir = new DirectoryIterator($path);


    foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
        if ($fileinfo->isDir() && !$fileinfo->isDot()) {
            $subPath = $path.$fileinfo->getFilename();
            $subDir = new DirectoryIterator($subPath);
            $count = count(glob($subPath. "/*.*"));

            $SubCount = 0;
            $subCategory = '';
            foreach ($subDir as $subDirPath) {

                if ($subDirPath->isDir() && !$subDirPath->isDot()) {
                    $subDirPathDetails = $subPath.'/'.$subDirPath->getFilename();
                $subDirDetails = new DirectoryIterator($subDirPathDetails);
                $subDircount = count(glob($subDirPathDetails. "/*.*"));

                    $SubCount = $SubCount + $subDircount;
                    $subCategory.= '<li><a href="#">'.$subDirPath->getFilename().'<span>'.$subDircount.'</span></a></li>';

                }

            }
        echo $mainCategory = '<li><a href="#">'.$fileinfo->getFilename().'<span>'.$SubCount.'</span></a><ul class="sub-menu">';
        if(!empty($subCategory)){
             echo $subCategory; // sub category li*/
        }
            echo '</ul></li>';

        }

    }
    echo '</ul>';

?>
```

Comment: What is "before foor loop"? also is your provided code an example, snippet or to replace all my code so far?

Comment: I mean comment this line from your code // echo '<li><a href="#">'.$fileinfo->getFilename().'<span>'.$count.'</span></a><ul class="sub-menu">';

Comment: So I comment that line out and add your code where?

Comment: replace your code (inner for loop only and echo statement above inner for loop) with above snippet.

Comment: Sorry, pretty new at PHP, this is quite advanced for how little I've been learning :)

Comment: Thank you a billion, I was just trying to get my head around doing this, did part then got confused again and even more when the code changed in front of my eyes :P One of those "OMG is that the time?!!!"  programming nights :P

Comment: Oh no! I've just realised it's not actually counting the files correctly :(

Comment: Category_1 > Sub_Category_1 has 22 files inside and Category_1 > Sub_Category_2 has 14 files inside...

Comment: Sorry, I never meant the adding of both, your adding of both prints perfectly but I thought my code was working perfectly adding how many files there were in the sub-categories...

Comment: for counting file inside folder do check (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801370/count-how-many-files-in-directory-php).

Comment: Okay and you should revert your code back as this breaks the script and no-longer adds up

Comment: your current code does not work - It breaks my page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69273/discussion-between-tim-marshall-and-kamlesh-bar).