# How to count number of .txt files in a directory in PHP?

Tags: php, file, file-handling

I'm working on an IMDB style website and I need to dynamically find the amount of reviews for a movie. The reviews are stored in a folder called `/moviefiles/moviename/review[*].txt` where the `[*]` is the number that the review is. Basically I need to return as an integer how many of those files exist in that directory. How do I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use php DirectoryIterator or FileSystemIterator:

```
$directory = new DirectoryIterator(__DIR__);
$num = 0;
foreach ($directory as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
        if($fileinfo->getExtension() == 'txt')
            $num++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice to see somebody using [DirectoryIterator()](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php). This kind of task is exactly why that iterator exists.

Answer (score 2):

First, use [glob ()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to get file list array, then use [count ()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) to get array length, the array length is file count.

Simplify code:

```
$txtFileCount = count( glob('/moviefiles/moviename/review*.txt') );
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `glob()` function: http://php.net/manual/de/function.glob.php
You can then use `sizeof()` to count how many files there are.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this php code to get the number of text files in a folder

```
<div id="header">
<?php 
    // integer starts at 0 before counting
    $i = 0; 
    $dir = 'folder-path';
    if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false){
            if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..')) && !is_dir($dir.$file)) 
            {
                $temp = explode(".",$file);
                if($temp[1]=="txt")
                    $i++;
            }
        }
    }
    // prints out how many were in the directory
    echo "There were $i files";
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple code that works well. :)

```
$files = glob('yourfolder/*.{txt}', GLOB_BRACE);
foreach($files as $file) {
    your work
}
```