# PHP iterate through directory

Tags: php

I am trying to iterate through a directory that has files in folders.

All I want to do is get the path to the files and iterate through the directory's to get all the files then list them.

I come up with this but it doesn't seem to iterate through

```
<?php
        function checkdir($dir)
        {
                foreach (new DirectoryIterator($dir) as $file) {
                        if($file->isDir())
                        {
                            $newdir = $file->getRealPath();
                            checkdir('$newdir');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo $file->getRealPath() . "<br>\n";
                        }
                }
        }
checkdir('./');

?>
```

I'm a bit stuck as to why its not working so any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909820/how-to-recursively-iterate-through-files-in-php

Comment: Probably because you do not have any folder that is _literally_ named `$newdir`. Why did you put single quotes around this variable in the checkdir call?

Comment: @Hind Sagar Biswas Thats just what I need thank you

Comment: ... and remember to exclude '.' and '..'