# PHP-view filenames without selecting subfolder

Tags: php

this is my directory

```
D:
|--SMUE
  |--a.pdf
  |--b.pdf
  |--file_1
     |--c.pdf
  |--file_2
     |--d.pdf
```

and below is my coding

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/search_icon.png">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Retrieval System</title>
        <link href="templatemo_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php

          foreach (glob("D:/SMUE/*.pdf") as $filename) 
          {
            echo "$filename <br/>";
          }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried this coding for viewing files name under the SMUE directory and it work but it only view filenames for  a.pdf and b.pdf only.

How can i view the filenames  fro c.pdf and d.pdf file too? is there any solution.?
*i want to view all filenames (that .pdf only) under the SMUE folder

Comment: Did you try to look at the notes? Solution is there http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109042/php-get-file-listing-including-sub-directories

Comment: you already have the duplicate, the answers there will help you, actually you could just change the file path

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP- retreiving filenames from a multifolder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26457998/php-retreiving-filenames-from-a-multifolder)

Comment: thanks.. its help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109042/php-get-file-listing-including-sub-directories