# Using glob to find all files

Tags: php, file, glob

I am trying to find all files that exist in all subdirectories and the root folder with the `glob()= function. My code is like this:

```
chdir("/var/www/dwnlds/files");
foreach(glob("*") as $file) {
    print $file;
}
```

This code just prints from the current directory, so therefore I have tried to use this code:

```
 `glob("*/*");`
```

but that does **only** print the files in sub-directories, not in the root folder, and it does not continue to scan all subdirectories either, it just stops after the first (because of the pattern i have set of course) but what pattern or function can I use to find all files in all possible directories from the working directory?

Comment: glob is not recusive. that's something you'll have to do yourself, or use a [directoryiterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109042/php-get-file-listing-including-sub-directories