# get all files in subdirectories

Tags: php

I need to move all files from all subdirectories into one folder.

So I need to have all paths of the files. I found this code:

```
function recurseDir($dir) {
if(is_dir($dir)) {
    if($dh = opendir($dir)){
        while($file = readdir($dh)){

            if($file != '.' && $file != '..'){
                if(is_dir($dir . $file)){
                    recurseDir($dir . $file);
                }else{
                    foreach(glob($dir.'/*.*') as $file1) {
                        echo $file1."<br />\r\n";
                    }                        
                }
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($dh);         
    }
  }
```

However somehow it prints prints all files the amount of times there are files in the folder.

Can someone see where I made the error?

EDIT:

The return after the echo worked for the duplication,however this goes only one subfolder deep so it stops after checking the first subfolder.

Comment: Try adding `return;` after your `foreach` loop

Comment: Great thanks this worked.

Comment: You know you use [PHP glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) see also examples here [php-get-file-listing-including-sub-directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109042/php-get-file-listing-including-sub-directories) especially [this answer for recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15681504/2008111)

Comment: @caramba This worked really nice indeed

Comment: Actually I tried to say "you could use.." not "you use.."

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the directory separator ("/") in your function call.

Try this.

```
<?php
    function recurseDir($dir) {
        if(is_dir($dir)) {

            if($dh = opendir($dir)){
                while($file = readdir($dh)){
                    if($file != '.' && $file != '..'){

                        if(is_dir($dir. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file)){
                            recurseDir($dir .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. $file);
                        }else{
                            foreach(glob($dir.'/*.*') as $file1) {
                                echo $file1."<br />\r\n";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            closedir($dh);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This worked for the duplication however it only goes one folder deep, do you know what I'm missing?