# Php add comand for search file on subfolders

Tags: php

I have this script that works good, but I need to add a command for searching on all subfolders.

Example: I have a folder data and this contains more another folders... I need to search files on this folders.

```php
$dir = 'data'; 
$exclude = array('.', '..', '.htaccess'); 
$q = (isset($_GET['q'])) ? strtolower($_GET['q']) : ''; 
$res = opendir($dir); 

while(false !== ($file = readdir($res))) { 
    if(strpos(strtolower($file), $q) !== false &&!in_array($file, $exclude)) { 
        echo "<a href='$dir/$file'>$file</a>"; 
        echo "<br>"; 
    } 
} 

closedir($res);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109042/php-get-file-listing-including-sub-directories

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP get file listing including sub directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109042/php-get-file-listing-including-sub-directories)

Answer (score 0):

you can use scandir() function

```
$dir  = '/tmp';
$file = scandir($dir);
print_r($file);
```

Comment: Thanks but this no show me rezult on folder after use search from.This show me  Array ( [0] => . [1] => .. [2] => pdf1 [3] => pdf2 [4] => pdf3 )   I need search and show file from folders the pdf1,pdf2 and pdf3 is me.folders.Thanks you

Comment: I need help for add message notice on original script if the file not exist after search.Sample : File not found.

Comment: try this if (file_exists($filename)) {
echo "success";}else{
 echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}

Comment: Thanks! Please is posisble add the message "Wait file searching..." message on the script before file is found?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the recursive function you are looking for :

```php
function dir_walk($dir, $q) {
    $q = trim($q);
    $exclude = array('.', '..', '.htaccess'); 
    if($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while(($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            if(in_array($file, $exclude)) { continue; }
            elseif(is_file($dir.$file)) {
                if($q === '' || strpos(strtolower($file), $q) !== false) { 
                    echo '<a href='.$dir.$file.'>'.$dir.$file.'</a><br/>';
                    }
                }
            elseif(is_dir($dir.$file)) {
                dir_walk($dir.$file.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $q);
                }
            }
        closedir($dh);
        }
    }

$q = (isset($_GET['q'])) ? strtolower($_GET['q']) : ''; 
dir_walk('/data/', $q);
```

Edit: data need to be the absolute path to the main dir, with ending directory separator "/data/"

Comment: Thanks you,but not.worked..nothing rezult found..I need search file on folders and subfolders.Example I have folder data and this contains pdf1,pdf2 and pdf3 folders...I need search files on this pdf1..pdf2..pdf3... Thanks.

Comment: Here it works, but i have to put the absolute path, with ending directory separator, tested on windows with 'c:\\data\\'. Try debug it to match the is_dir() and is_file(). And use $_GET['q'] instead 'mysearch'.

Comment: I use HTML code for runn this php file on xmapp maybe this is problem?<form action="file.php" method="get">
<input name="q" type="text" /> 
<input type="submit" />
</form>

Comment: Have improve the code, retry this one. And dont forget to put your absolute/real path instead "/data/". If fail, try it without the form to debug it. Xampp on what OS ?

Comment: I use windows 10 64 bit version.

Comment: So put the absolute path to your main dir, for example like this "``C:\\Xampp\\www\\data\\``"

Comment: Thnaks.is possible please add on  me original script operation for search on more folders? On me example I can search only one single folder "data" I need search on more folders,Example data',data1', data2' ...and more....

Comment: You can add more dir_walk() with your others folders.

Comment: Worked!! I need help how add option for character search minim 3 characters inputs.Me form search minim 1 and max unlimited...I need add limit search form 3 characters typed input..thx