# list files inside directory of a directory

Tags: php

For looping all files in a directory, I created this code in php :

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator(dirname(__FILE__));
$files = scandir($dir.'/');
foreach($files as $file) 
{
    echo $file;
    echo "\n";
}
```

However I am not able to list all files inside multiple subdirectory of a directory.

Comment: Is __FILE___ a relative path from the current directory? Is so take of the ending '/' in the scandir

Comment: did you check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121479/listing-all-the-folders-subfolders-and-files-in-a-directory-using-php

Comment: @kyle: `__FILE__` is a [magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php), if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 5):

Use `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`

```
<?php

$path = realpath('/etc');

$objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
foreach($objects as $name => $object){
    echo "$name\n";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.  [See this in php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

```
function loop_dir($dir) {
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir),
                                              RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
    foreach ($iterator as $path) {
      echo $path
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like @GBD was answering at the same time and got in first.  Go with his.

Answer (score 0):

Simple as this:

```
$dir = dir('DIRECTORY_TO_DISPLAY_HERE');
while (($file = $dir->read()) !== false) {
    if ($file != '..' && $file != '.') {
        echo $file;
    }
}
$dir->close();
```

Comment: This does not go into sub-directories, which is what the question asks for.