# Get all the subfolders names and and all the html files in it

Tags: php, file

I have the folder structure like below

```
folder1
folder2
fodder3
```

and all these folderrs contains files like

```
blah.html
blabla.html
```

Now i can get the folder names with below code.But how can i also get all the html file names inside those folders ?(only html files not other files)

```
$dir= glob($path . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
```

Comment: Maybe duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121479/listing-all-the-folders-subfolders-and-files-in-a-directory-using-php

Comment: that solution returns all the files... i need to filter only html files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check, if it will help you.

```
foreach (glob($path . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dir) {
    $files = glob($dir . '/*.html');

    echo '<pre>'; print_r($files);
}
```

Comment: its returning other files too .. i need only html files

Comment: glob($dir . '/*.html') did the job..please update it.. i will accept ur answer