# Return the list of all files excluding directory in the folders subfolders recursively PHP

Tags: php

I want array with values as Name of files only in the folders sub folders recursively. It must not include name of sub folder or sub sub folders.
Please note I do not want to just print the name of files instead I want accumulative result as the execution finishes. 
I have tried [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121479/listing-all-the-folders-subfolders-and-files-in-a-directory-using-php)
and many other solutions already given with no luck (used array_merge to retain the Previous values)

[My code is here](http://pastebin.com/4Ni3MEQj)

Comment: please post your code

Comment: You need to show some code. There is lots of posts on SO on this topic I am sure you can find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that it's been answered before, but it's fun to play with recursion every once in a while, so here you go...

```
<?php
function listFolderFiles($dir=null)
{
    $rtn = array();
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        #echo '<ol>';
        foreach (new DirectoryIterator($dir) as $fileInfo) {
            if (!$fileInfo->isDot()) {
                #echo '<li>' . $fileInfo->getFilename();

                if ($fileInfo->isDir()) {
                    echo 'directory';
                    $rtn = array_merge($rtn, listFolderFiles($fileInfo->getPathname()));
                } else {
                    echo 'file';
                    $rtn[] = $fileInfo->getFilename();
                }
                #echo '</li>';
            }
        }
        #echo '</ol>';
    } else {
        echo "No such directory '$dir'";
    }
    return $rtn;
}
$result = listFolderFiles('\tmp');

echo "result=<pre>".print_r($result,true)."</pre><br />\n";
#print_r(array_unique($result));
```