# Find directory name and image names in it

Tags: php

I am using this short script to list images within a specific folder

```
$dirname = "images/gallery/Project 1/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");
foreach($images as $imagesm) {
print "$imagesm";
}
```

However, in folder gallery I have 3 folders (Project 1, Project 2, Project 3) and I want to make the script go through each folder automatically and print the images from them.

***For example:***

**Project 1**
- image 1
- image 2
- image 3

**Project 2**
- image 1
- image 2
- image 3

**Project 3**
- image 1
- image 2
- image 3

I know that I can just copy the script for each folder, but want it to happen automatically as I might add a folder Project 4 in the future

I guess I will just need to loop through the folders, but no idea how to do it.
Tried to do it this way, but it didnt work either

```
$dir = "images/gallery/";
$cdir = scandir($dir); 
    foreach ($cdir as $dirname) 
    {
$newdir="images/gallery/$dirname";
$images = glob($newdir."*.jpg");
foreach($images as $imagesm) {
print "$imagesm";
}
}
```

**Here is the final working code if someone is interested**

```
$mydir = 'images/gallery'; 
$subdirs = array_filter(glob($mydir . '/*'), 'is_dir');
foreach($subdirs as $dir){
  echo '<b>'.basename($dir).'</b><br>';
  $images = glob($dir . '/*.jpg');
  foreach($images as $image)
  {
    echo basename($image).'<br/>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listing all the folders subfolders and files in a directory using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121479/listing-all-the-folders-subfolders-and-files-in-a-directory-using-php)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a `$numFolders` variable that is the number of folders you have, then use [a `for` loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php):

```
$numFolders = 3; //change this to reflect the number of folders

for($i = 1; $i <= $numFolders; $i++){
    $dirname = "images/gallery/Project $i/";
    $images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");
    foreach($images as $imagesm) {
        print "$imagesm";
    }
}
```

This will loop through the code, going through each `Project $i` directory until it reaches the limit of `$numFolders`.

---

### Edit

For unknown folder names:

```
$root = "images/gallery/"; //your root folder

$folders = scandir($root); //get all file/folder names

foreach($folders as $f){

    //Check that $f is a valid directory
    if($f != "." && $f != ".." && is_dir($f)){

        //Get all files in the directory $f
        $images = glob($root.$f."*.jpg");

        //Print all images
        foreach($images as $i){
            print $i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thats a good idea, but what is I want to call the next folder Cat or Dog. Also, What I am trying to achieve is not to have human interaction if there is a new folder with pictures added.

Comment: @ Ben Pearl Kahan It doesn't work. It shows a blank page (no results) and I have checked that there are no syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 function dirToArray($dir) { 

    $result = array(); 
    $allowedtypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg');
    $cdir = scandir($dir); 
    foreach ($cdir as $key => $value) 
    { 
       if (!in_array($value,array(".",".."))) 
       { 
          if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value)) 
          { 
             $result[$value] = dirToArray($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value); 
          } 
          else if(in_array(pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_EXTENSION),$allowedtypes))
          { 
             $result[] = $value; 
          } 
       } 
    } 

    return $result; 
 } 

$dirname = "images/gallery";
$gallery_arr = array_filter(dirToArray($dirname));
echo '<pre>';print_r($gallery_arr);exit;
```

source:- [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    $images=[];
    $len=2;
        for($i=1;$i<=$len;$i++){
                $dirname = "images/gallery/Project " .$i ."/";
                 $images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");
                 foreach($images as $imagesm) {
                    print "$imagesm";
                } 
    }
    ?>

where $len is a number of folders that you have created.I give here $len=2 because i created **Project 1** and **Project 2**
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I took a bit of a different approach... and simple I believe. Here is the script I did that actually does exactly what I mentioned in the first post

```
$mydir = 'images/gallery'; 
$subdirs = array_filter(glob($mydir . '/*'), 'is_dir');
foreach($subdirs as $dir){
  echo '<b>'.basename($dir).'</b><br>';
  $images = glob($dir . '/*.jpg');
  foreach($images as $image)
  {
    echo basename($image).'<br/>';
  }
}
```

Thanks to everyone anyway.