# Laravel : How to get random image from directory?

Tags: php, image, laravel, random

I have a directory containing the sub-directory, in each sub-directory there are images. I want to display the images randomly.
Below my code in php that works well, but it does not work in Laravel, problem is with `opendir()` and `readdir()`.

view blade

```
<?php
$folder = opendir('images/');

$i = 0;
while(false !=($file = readdir($folder))){
if($file != "." && $file != ".."){
    $images[$i]= $file;
    $i++;
    }
}
$random_img=rand(0,count($images)-1);
?> 

<div>
<?php
echo '<img src="images/'.$images[$random_img].'" alt="" />';
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121479/listing-all-the-folders-subfolders-and-files-in-a-directory-using-php , you may get the list of files inside directory and sub-directories and then may put the random order.

Comment: Answered here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41166308/laravel-how-to-get-random-image-from-directory

Answer (score 5):

In Laravel you need to use [`Storage`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem) to work with filesystem.

```
$files = Storage::allFiles($directory);
$randomFile = $files[rand(0, count($files) - 1)];
```

Comment: I have error : syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ']'

Comment: Now I do not have an error message, but I am not receiving nothing in the page, the page is not fully charged!!!

Comment: This will have an out of bounds error if the count($files) is used. Need to change it to count($files) - 1.

Comment: I have edited it to be the correct answer without the potential error and now up voted it.

Comment: @robertmylne Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use `allFiles` method of Laravel to get all the files and get one of the images using your random logic.

```
File::allFiles($directory)
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can use `Laravel Filesystem` but to make it completely working, you've to setup the configuration. For example, the following code will not work:

```
$dir = 'images'; // public/images
$files = \Storage::allFiles($dir);
```

Because, the `Filesystem` uses configuration from `config/filesystems.php` where you may have something like this:

```
'disks' => [
    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],
    // ...
]
```

By default, `Laravel` uses `local` disk and it points to a different path. So, to make it working, you've to setup your disk in the config, for example, add the following entry into the array:

```
'web' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => base_path('public'),
],
```

Then, you may use something like this:

```
$dir = 'images'; // public/images
if($files = \Storage::disk('web')->allFiles('images')) {
    $path = $files[array_rand($files)];
}
```

To use this `$path` in your `view` use `<img src="{{asset($path)}}">`. [Check more here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/filesystem#configuration).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to do this. I am with have now laravel 5.7, but should work for older versions too.

```
$files = Storage::files('path/to/directory');
$randomFile = array_random($files);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Laravel method where you can return 1 or more random elements;

```
$all = Storage::allFiles($directory);

$rand = Arr::random($all, 1);
```

Dont forget the facade:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$files = Storage::allFiles($directory); 

$randomFile = $files[array_rand($files)];
```