# Laravel generating fake images from a specific path

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a business website with Laravel. I'm trying to generate fake images with a factory to make tests easier, but it's not working because I don't know **how to add the path of my images in the code**.

The code which generates fake data in database:

```php
use App\Product;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(Product::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    // $images = [];
    // $images[0] = '/img/fashion/1.jpg';
    // $images[1] = '/img/fashion/2.jpg';
    // $images[2] = '/img/fashion/3.jpg';
    // $images[3] = '/img/fashion/4.jpg';
    return [
        'category_id' => $faker->numberBetween($min = 1, $max = 3),
        'brand_id' => $faker->numberBetween($min = 1, $max = 3),
        'name' => $faker->word,
        'url' => $faker->word,
        'description' => $faker->sentence($nbWords = 6, $variableNbWords = true),
        'price' => $faker->numberBetween($min = 1, $max = 20),
        'content' => $faker->realText($faker->numberBetween(10, 20)),
        'image' => $faker->image('public/storage/images', 640, 480, null, false)
    ];
});
```

I saw a training video on YouTube in which we attach media information to a Laravel application via the package `spatie/laravel-medialibrary`, but it's not clear.

Can anyone please explain this?

Comment: Put the code in your question, not just an image.

Comment: Updated the sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the image using faker in the correct way.

You will need to run the following command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Following that, you can access the image using:

```
<img src="/storage/images/{{$product->image}}">
```

Comment: just to better understand, where does laravel take images to integrate in my application? from internet or what?

Comment: The Faker library takes images from the internet, specifically from http://lorempixel.com/ 

You can put images in your public/ folder within your project and use them as well. They would be accessed in the same way, you would just need to make sure you specify the correct path.

Comment: i've tried it and it works, now i want to use a folder in which there's images in my computer to do the same operation, what can i do?

Comment: You'd need to copy the images into your Laravel project. You should have a public folder, create a new folder in that called images and copy the images into that. You then just need to specify the file location then to load the image.

Comment: i did it but it doesn't work, i've changed the "public/storage/images" path into this path: "public/img" then i executed the factory method in laravel tinker to upload in my database but it always takes images from lorempixel

Comment: Ah, I understand what you mean now. I don't think you can tell faker to use your own images.

You would need to write your own logic to randomly choose images from that folder. Take a look at this to implement something: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41166308/laravel-how-to-get-random-image-from-directory

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer

```
function random_pic($dir)
{
    $files = glob($dir . '/*.*');
    $file = array_rand($files);
    return $files[$file];
}

$factory->define(Business::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        //
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'license' => random_pic('public/tmp/license')
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Laravel 8.

The value of `image`is the path on my local machine to store uploaded images in the `client` directory. When I ran this--`App\Models\Client::factory()->create()`-- in tinker an image was uploaded to the `clients` directory, and the image file name was stored in the database (see below). `image()`, I believe, requires five arguments.

[image]

[image]

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Client;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class ClientFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Client::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'first_name'  => $this->faker->firstName,
            'last_name'   => $this->faker->lastName,
            'email'       => $this->faker->unique()->safeEmail,
            'phone'       => $this->faker->phoneNumber,
            'image'       => $this->faker->image('public/assets/images/uploaded/clients', 400, 300, null, false),
            'address'     => $this->faker->streetAddress,
            'city'        => $this->faker->city,
            'state'       => $this->faker->stateAbbr,
            'zip'         => $this->faker->postcode,
            'country'     => $this->faker->country,
            'description' => $this->faker->paragraph
        ];
    }
}
```