# PHP script to dynamically generate links to the directory, subdirector and files present in current diectory

Tags: php

Below is the php script I found to dynamically generate links to files present in current directory. can anyone of u help me with php script to dynamically generate links to all the directory ,sub-directory and files present in the root directory.

```
<?php
$dir_open = opendir('.');

while(false !== ($filename = readdir($dir_open))){
    if($filename != "." && $filename != ".."){
        $link = "<a href='./$filename'> $filename </a><br />";
        echo $link;
    }
}

closedir($dir_open);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

** UPDATE ** To show file name instead of the full path

```
<?php
$directory = new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path);
$iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory);
$files = array();
foreach ($iterator as $info) {
    echo  '<a href="' . $info->getFilename() . '">' . $info->getFilename() . '</a><br />';    
}
```

Comment: hey this displays the entire path. 
i just want it to display the directory name, can u help me modify the code.

Comment: thanks for updating the code. 
i want to  generate links for all the directory , subdirectory and files.using this code im only able to print files. something like this 

favorite
29
Please give me a solution for listing all the folders,subfolders,files in a directory using php.My folder structure is like this

Main Dir
 Dir1
  SubDir1
   File1
   File2
  SubDir2
   File3
   File4
 Dir2
  SubDir3
   File5
   File6
  SubDir4
   File7
   File8

Answer (score 0):

use [scandir](http://php.net/manual/zh/function.scandir.php) to get all the files and all the directories in one directory, then use is_dir to make them apart.

```
<?php
$fileAndDir = scandir('/home/me');
if($fileAndDir !== FALSE)
{
    foreach($fileAndDir as $v)
    {
        if(is_dir($v))
            $dirs[] = $v;
        else
            $files[] = $v;
    }
}
print_r($files);
print_r($dirs);
```

For all subdirs refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121479/listing-all-the-folders-subfolders-and-files-in-a-directory-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by having index.php for each directory .. all having this code:

**INDEX.PHP**

```
<?php

$currentDir = dirname(__FILE__);
$subDir = scandir($currentDir);

$linkList = '<ul>';
foreach($subDir as $name)
{
$link = '<li>';
$myDirLink = '<a href="' . $name . '/index.php">' . $name . '</a>';
$myFileLink = '<a href="' . $name . '">' . $name . '</a>';
$link .= is_dir($name) ? $myDirLink : $myFileLink;
$link .= '</li>';
$linkList .= $link;
}
$linkList .= '</ul>';
echo $linkList;
?>
```

Comment: yea i agree , but im trying to get the same output with one index.php in the root directory. is that possible ?