# How to loop and get data of all nested files and subfolders

Tags: php, filesystems

I have a top folder named `home` and nested folders and files inside
I need to insert some data from files and folders into a table
The following (simplified) code works fine if I manually declare parent folder for each level separatelly, i.e. - `home/lorem/`, `home/impsum/`, `home/ipsum/dolor/` etc
Is there a way to do this automatically for all nested files and folders ?
Actually, I need the path for each of them on each level

```
$folders = glob("home/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
foreach($folders as $el){
    //$path = ??;
    //do_something_with folder;
}
$files = glob("home/*.txt");
foreach($files as $el){
    //$path = ??;
    //do_something_with file;
}
```

Comment: If you don't know the depth of the folder structure in advance you'll need to use an approach involving recursion

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Listing all the folders subfolders and files in a directory using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121479/listing-all-the-folders-subfolders-and-files-in-a-directory-using-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has the [recursiveIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiterator.php) suite of classes - of which the [recursiveDirectoryIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) is the correct tool for the task at hand.

```
# Where to start the recursive scan
$dir=__DIR__;

# utility
function isDot( $dir ){
    return basename( $dir )=='.' or basename( $dir )=='..';
}

# create new instances of both recursive Iterators
$dirItr=new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $dir, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::KEY_AS_PATHNAME );
$recItr=new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $dirItr, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST );

foreach( $recItr as $obj => $info ) {
    
    # directories
    if( $info->isDir() && !isDot( $info->getPathname() ) ){
        printf('> Folder=%s<br />',realpath( $info->getPathname() ) );
    }
    
    # files
    if( $info->isFile() ){
        printf('File=%s<br />',$info->getFileName() );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use [The Finder Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html#searching-for-files-and-directories)

```php
use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;

$finder = new Finder();
// find all files in the home directory
$finder->files()->in('home/*');

// To output their path
foreach ($finder as $file) {
    $path = $file->getRelativePathname();
}
```