# PHP recursive directory search using glob for multiple file types

Tags: php, glob

I have a bunch of folders with these file types spread across them *.mp4,*.flv,*.wmv,*.mov

```
/video/o/y/oyr800/clips/1.flv
/video/p/y/pyr800/clips/1.wmv
/video/q/y/qyr800/clips/1.mp4
/video/51/51.mov
/video/52/52.flv
```

I tried using this function to list the paths and filenames but it gives me a blank return:

```
print_r(rglob('{*.mp4,*.flv,*.wmv,*.mov}',GLOBAL_BRACE));

function rglob($pattern, $flags = 0) {
  $files = glob($pattern, $flags); 
  foreach (glob(dirname($pattern).'/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR|GLOB_NOSORT) as $dir) {
    $files = array_merge($files, rglob($dir.'/'.basename($pattern), $flags));
  }
  return $files;
}
```

Not sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Ended up using this:

```
print_r(rsearch("C:\wamp\www","/^.*\.(mp4|flv|wmv|mov)$/"));

function rsearch($folder, $pattern) {
  $dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($folder);
  $ite = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir);
  $files = new RegexIterator($ite, $pattern, RegexIterator::GET_MATCH);
  $fileList = array();
  foreach($files as $file) {
    $fileList[] = $file[0];
  }
  return $fileList;
}
```

Works great!