# Search for pdf files

Tags: php, foreach, glob, readdir, opendir

I have one little question, this is my code to list all files from a folder and subfolders;

```
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {

$allFiles = array();

while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
    if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
        if (is_dir($dir . "/" . $entry)){
            $allFiles[] = "D: " . $dir . "/" . $entry;
        }else{
            $extension = strtoupper(pathinfo($entry, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            $fileNoExten = pathinfo($entry, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $directory = substr(str_replace('/', ' > ', $dir), $rootLenOnce + 3);
            $listagem .= '<tr>';
                $listagem .= "<td><a href='../" . $dir . "/" . $entry . "' ' target='_blank'>" . $entry . "</a></td>";
                //$listagem .= "<td><small>" . $directory . "</small></td>";
                $listagem .= "<td>" . $extension . "</td>";
                $listagem .= "<td><a class='download-cell' href='../".$dir ."/". $entry."' ' download> <i class='fa fa-download' ></i></a></td>";
                $listagem .= "<td class='display-none'>" . $fileNoExten . "</td>";
                $allFiles[] = "F: " . $dir . "/" . $entry;
            $listagem .= '</tr>';
            echo "<pre>"; print_r(glob("*.pdf")); echo "</pre>";
        }
    }
}
closedir($handle);

foreach($allFiles as $value){
    $displayName = substr($value, $rootLen + 4);
    $fileName    = substr($value, 3);
    $linkName    = str_replace(" ", "%20", substr($value, $pathLen + 3));
    if (is_dir($fileName)) {
        myScanDirPdf($fileName, $level + 1, strlen($fileName),$rootLenOnce);
     }
   }
 }
 return $listagem;
}
```

what i need is to filtrate the search, to search only .pdf files.

Someone can help me plz!

Thks!

i try with the glob function, but not with great results.

Thks!

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25258678/2776343

Comment: @AndreaManzi thks! but don't work. :(

Comment: are you sure that $dir is fullpath of your directory?

Comment: @AndreaManzi yes

Comment: webserver have read permission in $dir folder?

Comment: @AndreaManzi yes

Comment: files have "PDF" or "pdf" extension?

Comment: @AndreaManzi, both.

Comment: this work for me: print_r(rsearch($dir, "/^.*\.(pdf)$/")); function rsearch($folder, $pattern)
    {
        $dir = new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($folder);
        $ite = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir);
        $files = new \RegexIterator($ite, $pattern, \RegexIterator::GET_MATCH);
        $fileList = array();
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $fileList[] = $file[0];
        }
        return $fileList;
    }

Answer (score 0):

When you are looping through each file, you can use

```
        if(stripos($fileName, ".pdf"))
```

Hope this will help

I have one more suggestion in listing all the files and subfolders.
You can use Recursive Iterator

```
$folderName = $_POST['folderName'];
$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($folderName);
$it  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir);
foreach ($it as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isDir()) {
    }elseif ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
        $fileName = $fileinfo->getFileName();
        if(stripos($fileName, ".pdf")) {
        //do what you need to do 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When i try with the "stripos" only show the files in the root foulder.

Thks!

Comment: @freixo, I have used this method to iterate through folders and sub folders to copy all pdf files. It worked for me

Comment: Try some more time, if it works accept my answer. Thanks

Comment: Ok thks, one little question, in my code, can i use the stripos? thks!

Comment: Yes, you can, When you have all the files in an array, loop through each file and use stripos or strpos depending on case sensitiveness.

Comment: foreach($allFiles as $value){
        $displayName = substr($value, $rootLen + 4);
        $fileName    = substr($value, 3);
        $linkName    = str_replace(" ", "%20", substr($value, $pathLen + 3));
        if (is_dir(stripos($fileName, ".pdf"))) {
            myScanDirPdf($fileName, $level + 1, strlen($fileName), $rootLenOnce);
        }
    }

Is correct? I only obtain all the files in the root foolder. :(

Sorry for my nooby

Comment: With this:
if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".." && stripos($entry, '.pdf') === false)

The form don't show the pdf files, but if i turn true, don't show nothing @Muhammed