# recursive search for php video gallery

Tags: php, recursion, video, gallery

Could someone possibly help me with some code for a video gallery?

Unfortunately, I am way out of my depth here, I'm passable at python, but html and the associated stuff is a mystery to me. I have the following code which works a treat provided all the files are in one folder, but the program I'm using saves everything in subfolders (which I cant change). The good thing about this is that it doesn't rely on any plugins / online java scripts etc... which is essential because there won't always be an internet connection. I have looked online and although I know what to do (a recursive search), I can't seem to adapt the code to work with this.

Any help would be brilliant, else I will be spending another night starring at the screen in vain.

Kind regards

Paul

```
  <div id="vid-gallery"><?php
  // (A) GET ALL VIDEO FILES FROM THE GALLERY FOLDER
   $dir = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "gallery" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
  $videos = glob($dir . "*.{webm,mp4,ogg}", GLOB_BRACE);

  // (B) OUTPUT ALL VIDEOS
  if (count($videos) > 0) { foreach ($videos as $vid) {
    printf("<video src='gallery/%s'>preload=auto</video>", rawurlencode(basename($vid)));
  }} 
?></div>
```

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/25258678/12232340

Comment: Do you know if advance the name(s) of the sub-folders which hold the movie files ? (or you don't ?)

Comment: Unfortunately not they are created automatically depending on the date